# Scratches - both light and deep

Tags: paint, paint-scratches

How on earth do I remove unsightly scratches from my paint work?  There are plenty and are down to the white undercoat. How do I remedy them?

Answer (score 4):

Light scratches can be polished and buffed out.  I won't detail how to do it here, you can find many tutorials online, but be careful - you CAN burn paint by polishing too hard or staying in one spot too long.

Deep scratches can only be repaired by painting.  Your local dealership will be able to sell you a paint bottle that matches your factory color (assuming you have a late model vehicle).  Once you fill in the scratch with new paint, use a very fine grit sandpaper (2000-3000) with water to level it out, then polish & buff as above.

Comment: Would this http://www.halfords.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/product_storeId_10001_catalogId_10151_productId_802181_langId_-1_categoryId_165610#dtab match your description?

Comment: that's it.  just make sure you keep it wet - the water rinses the particulates out of the paper and lubricates the surface.

Comment: Excellent - whats your opinion on rubbing compounds?

Comment: A quick word of warning, wet sanding takes off a lot of material very quickly.  You can only remove about 0.3 mils of clear coat safely before you risk permanently compromising your finish.  Go slowly and don't sand any more than you have to.